# Flashplayer not working on Chromium 18.10

Tags: flash

I had to reinstall my OS, was on 18.10 and reinstalled it. The flashplayer on Chromium was working before and now not. It keeps telling me to "Click to enable" but nothing happens. I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times but to no avail. It is working on Firefox but runs very eratically. In "Software and Updates" I have enabled Canonical Partners.

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Go to this addresss : `chrome://version` attach the output in question

Comment: How did you install Chromium? As a .deb archive or a snap?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue as follows:
1) I went to chrome://flags/#prefer-html-over-flash"
2) In the search bar I searched "flash"
3) I changed the setting of "Enable Ephemeral Flash Permissions" from "Default" to "Disabled"